# I don't understand the difference between "stackoverflow" and "programmers"

Tags: discussion

As the title says.

Damn you 30 characters.

Comment: Why are you asking on the *Game Development* Meta SE site? Shouldn't you ask on Meta SO or Meta Programmers?

Answer (score 1):

General rule if the question or answer involves code then it belongs on stackoverflow. If its about programming but not exactly about what letters are needed in a particular situation it belongs on programmers.

But there are FAQs for each site that tell you exactly what is supposed to be posted on each.

https://stackoverflow.com/faq

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score -2):

StackOverflow seems to be more inclusive. In the FAQ, SO includes "enthusiast programmers" while P says it is for "professional programmers".